# How do I Get memberOf attribute from ldap DirContextOperations

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I am tring to get a list of groups a user is a member of, currently I can get most attributes as follows

```
CustomLdapUserDetails.Essence essence = new CustomLdapUserDetails.Essence();
essence.setDn(dn);
Object passwordValue = ctx.getObjectAttribute(passwordAttributeName);
String givennameValue = (String)ctx.getObjectAttribute("givenname");
String snValue = (String)ctx.getObjectAttribute("sn");
String titleValue = (String)ctx.getObjectAttribute("title");
essence.setFirstname(givennameValue);
essence.setLastname(snValue);
```

but I cannot figure out how to get the memberOf attribute. If I output the whole DirContextOperations as a String I get the following

```
org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter: dn=uid=emp123 {rdn=uid=emp123,
whenCreated=20110816063203.0Z,
objectCategory=CN=fompanyPerson,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={9F17F445-56C4-42D9-
B7C6-B630FFEA7F07}, badPwdCount=0, otherTelephone=123-456789, businessUnit=IREIRE BU, 
ntAccount=DMN1\emp123, managerID=emp987, objectGUID=5?
?e6A??????/, mail=emp123@somewhere.com, uid=emp123, companyWorkRelationship=EMP, 
memberOf[0]=CN=ABC IREIRE,OU=AutoGroups,DC=entdir,DC=gtn,DC=com, 
memberOf[1]=CN=azgEntJazzUsers,OU=AutoGroups,DC=entdir,DC=gtn,DC=com, companySite=DBL, 
companyCostCenter=91827, companyBusinessGroup=IREIRE BG, ntDomain=DMN1, instanceType=4, 
corpID=emp123, objectSid=  I???&?C?k?J???????, st=XX, badPasswordTime=0, vdejoindn=P-
ENTDIRXXX-1:uid=emp123,DC=entdirXXX,DC=gtn,DC=com, companySourceSystem=C-WORKSYSTEM, 
objectClass[0]=top, objectClass[1]=person, objectClass[2]=organizationalPerson, 
objectClass[3]=user, objectClass[4]=inetOrgPerson, objectClass[5]=fompanyPerson, 
company=ABC DEV, name=emp123, sn=Smith, exchangeAlias=emp123, telephoneNumber=1-987-6543, 
ntDomainRelative=DMN1, uSNChanged=999111, physicalDeliveryOfficeName=DXI, 
ntAccountRelative=DMN1\emp123, cn=Smith, John, exchangeServer=someServer, 
documentumUserName=Smith JOHN emp123, title=SOFTWARE ENGINEER/DEVELOPER, 
otherCertMailbox=emp123@xyz.somewhere.com, msDS-UserAccountDisabled=TRUE, 
managerName=Bloggs, Joe, givenName=John, uSNCreated=18418957, displayName=Smith, John, 
pwdLastSet=629579433359695509, fompanyPersonStatus=A, whenChanged=20120266070711.0Z, 
o=IREIRE BU, distinguishedName=uid=emp123,DC=entdirXXX,DC=gtn,DC=com, eDARevoke=N, 
division=SEF-GL , manager=uid=emp987,DC=entdirXXX,DC=gtn,DC=com, 
exchangeDirectory=SMXZG1DB, samAccountName=emp123, sametimeServer=cvxcluster}
```

What I need to get is the CN value of each memberOf into an array of Strings, I have tried:

```
ctx.getObjectAttribute("memberOf[1]"))
ctx.getObjectAttribute("memberOf"))
ctx.getObjectAttribute("memberOf=CN"))
```

I've seen examples online of setting but I could not find any examples of getting, is it really that much more complex then getting the other Attributes?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably only miss one "s" from the end. Try:

```
ctx.getObjectAttributes("memberOf")
```

The javadoc clarifies what's the difference between the [singular](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/DirContextOperations.html#getObjectAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and [plural](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/DirContextOperations.html#getObjectAttributes%28java.lang.String%29) form method. (The former only returns the first value even if the given attribute is multi-valued.)

Comment: I got Object Array after applying above solution.Now, I want to parse that String object to get group of authenticated user, what should I do? Should I parse string or Is there any LDAP utility that can give me authenticated user group?
I am getting below String Array.
cn=admin,cn=users,cn=example,cn=org
cn=team1,cn=users,cn=example,cn=org
cn=team2,cn=users,cn=example,cn=org

From above output, It is clear that authenticated user is member of 3 groups i.e admin,team1,team2

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Active Directory as your LDAP provider?
Not all LDAP providers have a memberOF attribute on the user.

The proper method to get groups of a user would be to search groups for a filter like:

```
(member=<fully distinguished name of user>)
```

Returning attribute "CN".

Comment: It's only 'proper' *if* there is no `memberOf` attribute. Otherwise it is many times slower and therefore quite improper.

Comment: The problem is further that `memberOf` is not part of the LDAPv3 schema.